# How to convert JSON into Apex Map

Tags: apex, json, map

JSON:

```
{parentComponentType=(
  {componentsList=( 
    {componentName=Class1, isSelected=True, lastModifiedByName=FirstName LastName, lastModifiedDate=}, 
    {componentName=Class2, isSelected=False, lastModifiedByName=FirstName LastName, lastModifiedDate=}
   ), 
   type=ApexClass
  }, 

  {componentsList=(
    { componentName=Page1, isSelected=True, lastModifiedByName=FirstName LastName, lastModifiedDate=}, 
    { componentName=Page2, isSelected=False, lastModifiedByName=FirstName LastName, lastModifiedDate=}
   ), 
   type=ApexPage
  }
)}
```

So far I did tried following :

```
public static void parse(String jsonStr){ 
  Map<String, Object> mapParent = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonStr); 

List<object> data2 = (List<Object>)data.get('parentComponentType');
System.debug('---*** dataMap2 :' + data2);
/* Debug I got :    
---***dataMap2 :({componentsList=({componentName=Class1, isSelected=True, lastModifiedByName=FirstName LastName, lastModifiedDate=}, 
{componentName=Class2, isSelected=False, lastModifiedByName=FirstName LastName, lastModifiedDate=}), type=ApexClass}, 
{componentsList=({componentName=Page1, isSelected=True, lastModifiedByName=FirstName LastName, lastModifiedDate=}, 
{componentName=Page2, isSelected=False, lastModifiedByName=FirstName LastName, lastModifiedDate=}), type=ApexPage})
*/
}
```

Comment: You can use this site to convert your json to Apex https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/, just paste your json there it will automatically generate the apex for that

Answer (score 2):

Below code should help you:

```
private map<string, string> parseJSONToMap(string JSONValue){
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(JSONValue);
    map<string, string> jsonMap = new map<string, string>();
    string keyValue = '';
    string tempValue = '';
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if(parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME){
            keyValue = parser.getText();
            parser.nextToken();
            tempValue = parser.getText();
            jsonMap.put(keyValue, tempValue);            
        }
    }
    return jsonMap;
}
```